# Visual Studio Debugger is crashing while try to start remote Debugging on Preempt-RT Ubuntu Linux

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cmake, cross-platform, ubuntu-18.04

I just installed a linux machine with a Preempt-RT patch (5.2.21-rt13) and installed manually all needed packages to remote debug on this machine.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server g++ gdb make rsync zip
```

Changing the Visual Studio connection manager worked, the output shows the rsync connection working properly, the cmake command with building and linking to the executable are with some warinings while building but no error is presented.
After those succesfull steps Visual Studio is trying to start the debugger, with no error code, just give no response.
 
After clicking abort it shows the following error, which tells not much about the state of the debug initialization.

I know that my project is working since i have another machine running with Ubuntu (5.0.0-32-generic) and the project is working on it just by changing the connection.

Did I miss a package on the new machine? Can I get a better overview about Visual Studio Debugger initialization?

The debug initialization shows:

[image: Debuginit]

The cancel dialog shows:

[image: canceldialog]

Comment: Can you please post the error you are seeing?

Comment: [Debug Initialization][1]  


If I press cancel the error will be:  
[Cancel Dialog][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBNGz.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7ZQB.png

Sorry for german message dialogs

Answer (score 1):

I'll found the answer for my Issue, it looks like Visual Studio has some troubles with getting the root rights which I need for my project (see my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492075/starting-a-cmake-built-application-with-administrative-priviliges-from-visual-st/56537537#56537537)).

I edited the **/etc/sudoers** by removing

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) ALL:ALL
```

and adding

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I don't know if there is a better way, but it was a solution for my case.

cheers.